# Angular - routerLink inside routerLink

Tags: html, angular, routerlink

I have one problem: I have:

```
<div class="list-group-item clearfix dictionaryItem" style="cursor:pointer" [routerLink]="[index]">

  <div class="pull-right">
    <img src="/assets/delete-icon.png" width="25" height="25" (click)="onDelete()">
  </div>
</div>
```

I'd like to call ONLY onDelete() method when clicking on  and go to another page ONLY when clicking my main ).

How can I do that? Or maybe my thinking is wrong? Maybe should I take another approach?

I'd like the whole main div to be like the button.

Thank you in advance!
Mateusz

Comment: Sounds like you maybe want to implement a RouteGuard https://angular.io/guide/router#guards

Comment: No, I don't think so. I could thanks to RouteGuard create a new flag onlyIMGWasClicked: boolean and with this flag on method canActivate check if I can go to the proper page or not...Hmm the question is if this approach is professional

Comment: i think you can put in your (click)="onDelete($event)" function  event.stopPropogation() method. This will stop propagate event when you click on your delete button but you still can click on all your block (except delete button) and go to the index page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to pass `$event` to the `onDelete()` method and call [`stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) on it:

```
onDelete(event) {
  // do whatever you want to do
  event.stopPropagation();
}
```

Html:

```
<img src="/assets/delete-icon.png" width="25" height="25" (click)="onDelete($event)">
```

[Sample on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-routed?file=app%2Fhome.component.ts)

Comment: AAAAh, I completely forgot about stopPropagation(). It works without problems. Thank you!!!